# Quartz.NET - paused jobs

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET in an application I am creating, and I give users the option of pausing the jobs/triggers as required. One issue I have is that if a job is paused when it was due to execute, when it's resumed it executes straight away - I'd want it to wait until the next time it should run, i.e. if it's every minute it'd wait til the next minute.

Is this an option in Quartz/Quartz.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using .StandBy instead of pause. Pause will apply the misfire instruction, StandBy will not.

This might help:
<s>http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic94.html</s>

**UPDATE (broken link)**

http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/apidoc/1.0/html/topic94.html

Note this is version 1 documentation. I assume the same rules apply to v2 but could not see any documentation to confirm or deny.